# One to many relationship with User authenitcation

Tags: python, django

I looked at many examples, but cant figure out how to do this with currently authenticated user while properly linking them. Basically I want on submit an update to db with an item that is related through unique user id or user name.

Users are unique but they can contain numerous items in Watchlist. User submitting, is currently logged in and authenticated.

***models.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)   
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

class WatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

***views.py***

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.user = request.user.id
    obj.save()
```

How can I link two models with authentication?

**Update 1**
Error traceback after

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and

```
 obj.user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)


Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\News\webservice\stoxspy\mysiteapp\views.py" in watchlist
  73.             obj.user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in insert_query
  1511.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  898.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  450.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /watchlist/
Exception Value: column user_id is not unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I helped the OP solve it at the Python chat. Just posting the gist here.

You did change the field type to `OneToOneField` but didn't migrate the changes. Hence the `.get()` method is complaining because `OneToOneField` would have the `UNIQUE` flag turned on for that field in DB. Because you didn't migrate, Django threw an integrity error, because your django model said that field should be unique but the DB said it's not.

Run your migration and you should be able to see that South is setting `unique=True`. That should solve the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in the WatchList model is create the attribute user as a ForeignKey to UserProfile in the same way you have linked UserProfile with User.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

--- UPDATED ---
Remember, request.user is an User instance, not UserProfile and before to set obj.user you need to get the UserProfile linked to that User.

```
obj.user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: check updated post, honestly I looked at the page for way too long before posting and I think I self confused even more

Comment: `column user_id is not unique` where
`"user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "mysiteapp_userprofile" ("id")`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the relationship between User and UserProfile should be a OneToOneField, not a ForeignKey. Then you'll be able to get the profile just via `request.user.userprofile`, and assign it to your watchlist exactly as you are already doing.

Comment: i thought one to one create unique items, and I need many items on a watchlist linked to this user

Comment: What? I said the relationship between User and UserProfile is OneToOne, not the relationship between UserProfile and Watchlist.

Comment: User is called with `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
what OneToOne are you talking about?

Comment: I don't understand how I can possibly make it clearer. You have a ForeignKey from UserProfile to User. That should be a OneToOneField.

Comment: Got you! Misread it a bit, getting same error as with Darwin below
`column user_id is not unique`

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Please slow the full code and traceback (preferably in an edit to your question).

Comment: Updated with traceback. Pretty sure issue is with
`CREATE INDEX "mysiteapp_watchlist_6340c63c" ON "mysiteapp_watchlist" ("user_id")` hence the unique issue? `user_id` should not be unique.